# TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable(is ok in windows, but have this error in linux)

Tags: python, django, manage.py

It can run successfully in Windows，but have a typeError when I want to run it in Linux.

**Description:**

- [linux]Using Django==1.11, python==3.6 and mysql-connector-python==2.1.6
- [windows]Django==1.10, python==3.6 and mysql-cinnector-python==2.1.6

[the error picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XkVcr.jpg)

thanks!

Comment: Can you show the part of the code which gives the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The version of `mysql-connector-python` in the Python Package Index is old and doesn't have the required bugfix that makes it compatible with Django 1.11. You can install 2.1.7 directly:

```
pip install https://cdn.mysql.com/Downloads/Connector-Python/mysql-connector-python-2.1.7.tar.gz
```

Note that [Django recommends](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/databases/#mysql-db-api-drivers) you use [`mysqlclient`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mysqlclient), so you might have an easier time using it.